# How do you perform version control on TeX-related files that are used in multiple projects?

Tags: external-files, git

I'm an avid TeX user for quite some time now. I use LaTeX for most of my lecture notes and my assignments. That's why I'm usually working on about half a dozen LaTeX projects at a time. Over the time I have accumulated quite a lot of my own commands and environments which I store in a file `makros.tex`. I also have one large `.bib` File to store literature.

Since I only want to have a central copy of this file I used the following method for the last months:

- Store the centralized files, `makros.tex`, `lit.bib` etc in a central folder called `includes`
- Create a sym-link to this folder and put this link into my project folder
- use `\include{includes/makros.tex}` etc in my project.

Now here is my problem: I started using git a few weeks ago for my C++ projects and became a really big fan of it. Hence I now want to use git for my TeX Projects as well. The Problem is however, that git doesn't really play well with symbolic links. Hence the folder `includes` is not actually uploaded.

How do you guys treat files you use for every project? I would really be interested in a file structure / workflow that accomplishes the following:

- The files `makros.tex` and `lit.bib` are stored at only one location, in a folder `includes/` on my computer.
- I can include them in every project.
- When I push my project to GitHub or Bitbucket the folder `includes/` also gets pushed, that way, when a friend downloads my repo, he can compile my notes without me having to send him the `includes/` folder.

In case this matters: I'm using Mac OS X as my primary and Ubuntu as my secondary OS.

Comment: How about creating a git repository for the shared code and include it as a submodule?

Comment: Tried it out right now, works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that from the point of view of just including the stuff in TeX, putting your files in a suitable subdirectory of `${TEXMFHOME}` is a good solution. Then you do not need the symbolic link although you might want that for use with your version control system, of course. For example `${TEXMFHOME}/tex/latex/makros/makros.tex`, `${TEXMFHOME}/bibtex/bib/lit.bib` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [git
submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Place the
shared code in a directory and create a git repository as usual. Then you can
add this repository to other projects as a submodule:

```
git submodule add <URL> <name>
```

When you clone the repository you can use the the `--recursive` switch to automatically pull in the submodules:

```
git clone --recursive <URL>
```

Using submodules ensures that the code is not duplicated and it is easy to include the code in other projects. Furthermore, submodules are a git feature and pose no problems for GitHub or Bitbucket.

[git submodule - man
page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)

Comment: Assuming that I publish the main project on Bitbucket, do I have to publish the "include" repository as well? Or is the data stored inside the main projects repo?

Comment: @FlorianW The data itself is not stored in the main repo, only pointers in `.gitmodules`, `.git/config` and the submodule git repo in `.git/modules/`. If you want to make your repository usable you have to publish the submodules as well, otherwise no one can clone the repositories using `--recursive`. A non-recursive clone will still succeed but the TeX compilation will fail because of missing files.