# How do I share a style file which is used by multiple git repositories?

Tags: packages, git

I am working with multiple LaTeX projects at any given point in time,
each of which is stored in a separate git repository.
I have also accumulated a set of commands and environments which I am familiar with
which help me to save time when writing LaTeX code.
My question is how to merge the style file contained in each git repository
into a single style file that can be shared across git repositories.

---

Currently, in each git repository I have a single style file
which I put in a localtexmf tree inside the git repository.
The file tree hierarchy might look like the following:

```
project-a/doc1/main.tex
project-a/doc2/main.tex
project-a/localtexmf/tex/latex/mymacros/mymacros.sty
```

This approach has the following advantanges:

1. All the documents in the git repository
   can share the same style file.
2. The style file is also under version control.

The disadvantage of this approach is that I have multiple style files
which share a lot of similar code, e.g.

```
project-a/localtexmf/tex/latex/mymacros/mymacros.sty
project-b/localtexmf/tex/latex/mymacros/mymacros.sty
project-c/localtexmf/tex/latex/mymacros/mymacros.sty
```

This results in unnecessary code duplication.
Often when I fix a bug or change a command definition,
I want the change to occur in all the `mymacros.sty` files.

---

What I want to do is to somehow have a single style file that is under version control,
but is shared by multiple git repositories.
How do I do this?

My operating system of choice is Ubuntu Linux or OS X.

Based on [How do you perform version control on TeX-related files that are used in multiple projects?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156323/how-do-you-perform-version-control-on-tex-related-files-that-are-used-in-multipl),
I suspect that `git submodule` is part of the answer.

Comment: Are you on a system which supports symlinks (Unix or admin privileges on Windows)?

Comment: @JosephWright See my edit to the question

Comment: I have a directory, `~/TeX`, where I put any personal style files that I use in many places. This directory is in its' own git repository and I have the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` set to `.:~/TeX//:` so that it is automatically searched by latex and friends.

Comment: @Andrew A problem with the approach you suggest is that if I want to recompile say the 2013-01-01 version of a particular project,  this version was compiled with a particular version of the style file which I will have to find by hand because the two versions are not tied together.

Comment: Yes, this is a potential issue. Typically I find that this is not a problem as most of my changes to these files are backwardly compatible "improvements". Of course, what you can do is also wind back the `~/TeX` repository to the date of the 2013-01-01 version and then compile - it is easy enough to find the dates in the git logs. If I needed to do this often then I'd write a hook for simultaneously winding back both repositories. As this is rarely a problem for me I haven't worried about it.

Comment: I do something not entirely dissimilar to @Andrew except that I'm using subversion rather than git. I actually have one repository, strictly speaking, so the version numbers are shared. But then I have three 'projects' or whatever within that (i.e. three trunks, four branches etc.): one for actual projects of kind 1, one for actual projects of kind 2 etc. and one for my texmf tree. ('Actual project' just means what I'd call a project as opposed to what I'm treating as a subversion 'project'.) This seems to work but, obviously, it is somewhat personal.

Comment: @Andrew After thinking it through, the approach that you take is simple and works well given that the changes I will likely make are as you say "backwardly compatible improvements." If you submit your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for sharing what you do. That approach also could work. For me I would prefer to separate my projects into different repositories so that they could be shared more cleanly with different people, i.e. one project concerns person A and B, another project should only be shared with person C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a directory, `~/TeX`, where I put any personal style files that I use in many places. This directory is in its' own git repository and I have the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` set to `.:~/TeX//:` so that it is automatically searched by latex and friends.

As the OP says in the comments, there is an issue in that repositories for the tex files and for the style will not always be in sync, which means that it can happen that an old commit will not compile because it requires a different version of the style files than those appearing in the current version of this. Typically I find that this is not a problem as most of my changes to these files are backwardly compatible "improvements". In any case, if an old commit does not compile then you can wind back the `~/TeX` repository to the date of the source file commit version and then compile - it is easy enough to find the dates in the git logs. If I needed to do this often then I'd write a hook/script for simultaneously winding back both repositories. As this is rarely a problem for me I haven't worried about doing this.